# Windows azure project architecture

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, architecture, azure-storage

I am new to windows azure plateform i want to ask a very basic question. I am doing a project on windows azure and due to some concurrency problems i want also my Browser GUI to be in the cloud which will call the web services which are also deployed in the cloud. 
Just need to ask that is it possible that i will also put my GUI in the cloud and i have some URL which i will hit so that my GUI will appear in the users browser...

I want my architecture some what like that

Sorry for the drawing but i am in very hurry
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your web browser would be on the user's desktop, and make a HTTP request to a web application/site that is hosted in Windows Azure.  For instance, an ASP.NET MVC web site that makes a service call to a WCF service, that then retrieves data from a SQL Azure database.  One way to do this would be to create a single hosted service that contains:

- Web Role (to host your ASP.NET site)
- WCF Web Role (to host your WCF service)
- SQL Azure (for your database)

Answer (score 0):

I think the web GUI you mentioned would be like an agent, it will connect to the real websit and render the content for you. If this is true I would like to say in theroy it's possible, but in practice it will be very difficult, since what you want to do is a web based web browser. You might need to handle HTML, CSS and JS, etc.. But if it's just a web ui that render your data from your service that is fine. So back to your question, when you said the "browser gui", if it's a desktop application, you cannot run it on the cloud; if it's a website then yes you can and your proposal looks fine.

Hope my feedback helps.